# Hosting a Citrix Server

Tags: citrix

One of my customers uses a Citrix server to allow their employees access to my MSACCESS application. I was curious about how I would go about hosting a Citrix server for some of my smaller customers who don't have IT departments. Any resources or thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a simple 2 server setup with a gateway at the edge with the Citrix Secure Ticketing running, then having a terminal server behind it servicing the app requests.

Or, just go with a Citrix hosting solution, like [THIS.](http://www.redplaid.com/citrix_hosting.html)

Comment: Smaller solutions would be best managed, and applied when you purchase already setup Citrix enviroments. To setup a full Citrix enviroment you will need PVS, ZDC, Desktop/Server delivery servers, applcation servers. 

I agree with DanBig, purchase a solution that is already setup and managed for something 20~ people or less and with a budget of $50,000 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Well depends on what you need, but for simple scenarios even vanilla remote desktop services can be enough.